# InetSocketAddress(URL, PORT) takes lot of time to throw exception

Tags: java, sockets, dns, network-programming, inet

1. Connection to Internet is removed.
   DNS is properly configured.

   Try running the following line:-

   `new InetSocketAddress(URL, PORT);`

   This takes around 56 seconds to throw UnknownHostException.
2. Connection to Internet is removed.
   DNS is not configured.

   Try running the following line:-

   `new InetSocketAddress(URL, PORT);`

   This takes less than 2 seconds to throw UnknownHostException.

Why?

Is there any solution to quickly throw Exception in Scenario 1?

Comment: Are you looking for [this method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetSocketAddress.html#isUnresolved())?

Comment: @Happy: No. I am not looking for isUnresolved(). Currently the constructor is taking lot of time of throw the exception. Should something to be done to throw the exception quick? This API is used widely I guess.

Comment: This is a strange behaviour, I can't reproduce. Moreover the documentation does not specify that the constructor throws this exception. Are you sure the exception isn't thrown elsewhere?

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12014938/3080094) the constructor calls `InetAddress.getByName(hostname)`. To rule out funky DNS behavior, what happens if you set the URL to an IP-address instead of a hostname?

Comment: The time is clearly lost when trying to connect to DNS server. The time will probably depend on system specific options like timeout for connection, number of retries, etc. Also number of DNS servers configured.

Comment: Clearly DNS isn't properly configured at all. How long does 'nslookup' take from that host using the hostname in the URL?